# Wait until a button is pressed

Tags: android

The application have a loop to fill a Byte array (infinite times until a button press, but stopping it is working), and there are 6 (Image)Buttons in the activity. The first ImageButton should insert into the array 0, the second should 1, and so on.

The activity and the thread:

```
public class TestMap extends AppCompatActivity {
  volatile private ImageButton a;
  volatile private ImageButton b;
  volatile private ImageButton c;
  volatile private ImageButton d;
  volatile private ImageButton e;
  volatile private ImageButton f;
  private boolean round0 = false;
  private static volatile boolean stop = false;


@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    a = findViewById(R.id.flag_a);
    b = findViewById(R.id.flag_b);
    c = findViewById(R.id.flag_c);
    d = findViewById(R.id.flag_d);
    e = findViewById(R.id.flag_e);
    f = findViewById(R.id.flag_f);
    Button end = findViewById(R.id.endturn);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!stop){
                round0 = true;
                for(int i = 0; i < squad_0.length; i++){
                        squad_0[i] = set_sqm0();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    round0 = false;
}
```

This stops the loop (and working):

```
public void endt(View view){
    stop = true;
}
```

And the not working part:

```
public Byte set_sqm0() {
    selected = 0;  //default value

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selected = 0;
        }
    });

   //the same is for b-f, the selected value is 1-5
    return selected;
}
```

The program fill the array with 0's without any button press, even if I delete the default value or edit a button's value to 6. Can someone help me how to pause the program until the user press the button?

Answer (score 1):

First you need not and should not call **a.setOnClickListener(...)** in **set_sqm0()** because this executes it continuously during every pass through the while loop in your thread. Same goes for the initialization of **selected = 0**, which is also executed in each iteration of the while loop, reseting **selected** to 0 after you press the button. You should move the **setOnClickListener()** calls and the initialization of selected in **onCreate()**, before the creation of the thread.